# How to get the letter of commitment of the host institution for ERC Calls?

Tags: funding, europe

For applying for European Commission grants, specifically ERC ADVANCED GRANT, I need to get an official letter from the host instuttion that they support my proposal.

**How is the procedure to get this letter?**

Do I need to contact the institution research office OR I need to find a collaborator in that institution to recommend me to get that letter?

Do they need to review my detailed proposal to decide if they want to support me OR they review my CV only?

How long does this process take?

Answer (score 1):

If you want another institution to provide you with space, office, computer access, mentoring, etc, then they will need to know and approve of your proposal. Every university has a sponsored research office (or other name) that is in charge of these things. Contact the department head or the university you want to host you to provide you with the necessary contacts.

Comment: Thanks my question is do I need to contact the university research office? or a department? In the latter case, my research can be hosted in different departments/centers. Maybe one is interested, one not.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you writing a proposal that says "Please fund my research, which I will do at university X"? If so, as a reviewer, I would immediately reject it if the proposal does not come with any kind of assurance that (i) the university will provide you with space, computers, resources, etc, (ii) that there is an organizational structure within which you will work, such as a department, a chair, a mentor, etc. To get all of this, you will need to have previous connections to that university. If you don't yet know a colleague or mentor, don't even apply!